# Webpack 4 configuration for react-toolbox

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, toolbox

I try to upgrade my app from webpack 2 to webpack 4.16.5.
Because I want not again end up in a hard to understand some hundreds line config, I start with a minimal config. This is my current:

```js
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const context = path.resolve(__dirname, "app");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    home: "./index.js"
  },
  context,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css", "json"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"), context]
  }
};
```

But I run in problems importing the CSS files from react-toolbox i.e.:

```js
import Dialog from 'react-toolbox/lib/dialog';
```

in a js file and also

```js
@import "react-toolbox/lib/button/theme.css";
```

causes errors like this:

```js
ERROR in ../node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/switch/theme.css (../node_modules/css-loader!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src!../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!../node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/switch/theme.css)
    Module build failed (from ../node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
    Error: composition is only allowed when the selector is single: local class name not in ".disabled", ".disabled" is weird
```

Does anyone have a working application with wbpack4 and react-toolbox? Also, any hints on what may cause these errors are welcome!

Answer (score -2):

I'm learning react.js with the [js stack from scratch](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch) tutorial and try to using react-toolbox components.

Finnaly, i have a working [demo](https://github.com/7anshuai/js-stack) with webpack 4 and the react-toolbox, it's based on the [react-toolbox-example](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-example).

This is my settings:

- add `css-modules` related packages

  `$ npm install postcss postcss-cssnext postcss-import postcss-loader css-loader style-loader`
- add a `postcss.config.js`

  `module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      'postcss-import': {
        root: __dirname,
      },
      'postcss-cssnext': {}
    },
  };`
- add a webpack rule

  `...
  { test: /\.css$/, use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: '[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]'
      }
    },
    'postcss-loader'
  ]},
  ...`
- add `cmrh.conf.js` - Using the `css-modules-require-hook` for SSR（Optional）

  `module.exports = {
    generateScopedName: '[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]'
  }`

You can see all the settings in [here](https://github.com/7anshuai/js-stack/commit/74e2967645aea7bec4620cda29dac0467185cf1c), hope it will work for you.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.